# How to put parameters(2nd grade array) to sub() ,,...void func( int* Array2nd)

Tags: arrays, c, ansi-c

```
void HowToPutParameters( XXXXXX)  // how to put parameters in XXXXXX
{
    array[0][0]=5; 
}    
void main()
{    
    int array[2][2]={{1,2},{3,4}};  
    HowToPutParameters(&array[0][0]);  // &array[0][0] is correct or &array[0]
}
```

// I wana put this array to HowToPutParameters;

// 1.I am not sure "&array[0][0] or &array[0]" are correct,The compiler seems identify;

// I've tried  void HowToPutParameters(int *array ) ==> compile failed

// I've tried  void HowToPutParameters(int *array[][] ) ==> compile failed

// My compiler is MPLAB X IDE V1.8 , Chip is Microchip>PIC32MX795F512

Comment: Your title suggests you want to pass the entire 2D array, but your code suggests one element. Which is it?

Comment: Well they have to graduate from 1st grade first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want use pass two dimensions array params,use:

```
 void func(int (*a)[2]);// tell the function the first dimension size!
 func(array);
```

It is the same as:

```
 void func(int a[][2]);
 func(array);
```

If you pass `&array[0][0]`, it means you pass a pointer point to a int.

```
void func(int *element);
```

Comment: The first is a pointer to an array of two pointers, and the second a pointer to an array of two integers. I prefer to put what it truly is, to avoid people trying to do `sizeof` on the pointer. That would be `int(*a)[2]`, which is what the second truly is, and is what `array` decays to.

Comment: It does work , Thanks very much.
void func(int a[][2]);
 func(array);

Answer (score 1):

Like this, in your code you are only passing a pointer to an `int` element of the array, not the array itself.

```
void HowToPutParameters(int* element)
```

And you should always use `int main` instead of `void main`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , however , it was my first try. As I though, whatever how many grade array has , it's just a ptr, but I am sorry to say , it doesn't work.

Comment: @user2684531, Arrays are not pointers. That misconception will only screw you over.

Comment: @user2684531 What do you mean by not working? This is according to what you are passing as argument in the code, maybe you should modify that part to reflect what you mean.